# Centering Icons in Bootstrap 4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app that I'm building with Bootstrap 4. I need to center some icons underneath an image. I have a Bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/gjUzXAv9lB). My code looks like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <img alt="Picture" src="http://cdn.bgr.com/2015/11/bill-gates.jpg" class="img-circle center-block" style="max-height:6.0rem;">
          <br>
          <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" style="font-size:1.2rem;"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" style="font-size:1.2rem;"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#" style="font-size:1.2rem;"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div><strong>Bill Gates</strong></div>
          <p>
            Here is some information about Bill Gates.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My question is, how do I horizontally center the three icons underneath my image so that it looks like a centered toolbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On your UL tag, remove the inline-list class, it's enforcing a float.